# subtyping relationships in OO paradigm

Tags: data-modeling, object-oriented-analysis

Let us consider a class 'Human' -->(1..*) 'Human' , where Human is a supertype. Say it has subclasses like 'Male', 'Female', 'SociallyPathologicalMale' etc. The basic association b/w 2 entities remains common, the subtypes define name and constraints on the association but the basic relationship is still m:n b/w 2 Human entities. 
Example:-

- 'Male' -->(1:1)('wife'(relationship name)) 'Female'
- 'Female'-->(1:1)('husband') 'Male'
- 'SociallyPathologicalMale'-->(1:0)('friends') 'Male'

  [edit 13/12/2011] - If say we have to implement it in java, what are some of the best practices such that reuse of the association possible?

Say we start with base class :-

```
 class Human{
  private List<Human> relationships; // in a subclass this field, could 
//  this generically be represented ?? 
}
```

something like

```
   class Man extends Human{
    private List<Woman> relationships;//should be 0 or 1
    }
```

Now the fact that relationships field is redefined in Man (or any other subclass) could be structurally enforceable , i.e while defining any subclass it should be mandatory for me to define out the relationships. Is it possible for such a kind of construct in java ?? are there other languages that can do this easily ??

Answer (score 0):

Two methods of implementation i would use would be Inheritance and Composition.

The `is a` relationship is expressed with inheritance and `has a` relationship is expressed with composition.

Both inheritance and composition allow you to place sub-objects inside your new class. Two of the main techniques for code reuse are class inheritance and object composition.

`Inheritance`

```
class Human {
//some code
}
class Male extends Human {
//some code
}
```

`Composition`

```
class Male
{
     Wife mrs = new Wife();
}
```

Comment: Hi Darren , thanks for the answer. I felt my question was not clear enough , so edited and tried to nail the main thing i was seeking, please see the edit part and you may like to add to your answer here

Answer (score 0):

There are two important things you should review from your scenario:

1) Fields cannot be redefined by subclasses. It is not a limitation of the language (Java) but a conceptual imposition that is reasonable. Fields define what an object **is** and methods define what an object **does** and **how**. The only thing you can redefine is **how** things are done by your objects but you are not allowed to change what your superclass **is** or **does**. (I'm saying "objects" but please keep in mind that I mean "the instances of the class" since you actually define the behavior in the class body).

2) You must make the Relationship a first-class object. Since it is not enough using what the paradigm provides you: "is a" and "has a". As Darren Burgess stated, the paradigm provides you with two conceptual relationships: "is a" and "has a". For the *Human->Man* or *Human->Woman* example, you can use inheritance, in other words, "is a". The Man class extends Human because *a Man is a Human*. The difficulty is on the "has a" relationship since OOP does not allows you to specify cardinality and you also want to specify a name on the relationship. For simplicity, let's define relationships as binary. For example, *A man has a Wife* or a *Woman has a Husband*. For the relationship *John is the father of Tom and Linda*, we will define two relationships: *John is the father of Tom* and *John is the father of Linda*. The problem with your approach is that you specified a List of Man and a List of Woman. However, what a Human actually has is a Collection of **Relationships**. The design will look like this:

```
public Human {
    private Collection<Relationship> relationships;
}

public Relationship {
    private Human party; // We are defining only relationships between humans.
    private Human counterparty;
    private String name; // e.g., "is the Husband of" and "is the Wife of".
}
```

Party and counterparty are the members of the relationship and the object instance of Relationship will represent how one relates to the other.

Defining particular behavior would be more ad-hor. For example, a **SociallyPathologicalMale** will not have any **Relationship**. You can add the following method to **Human**:

```
public void addRelationship(Relationship newRelationship) {
    relationships.add(newRelationship);
}
```

The SociallyPathologicalMale class (who extends Male) will inherit that method and will redefine it as follows:

> public void addRelationship(Relationship newRelationship) {
>       // Nothing to do here. }

Basically, as SociallyPathologicalMale, by definition, is unable to have any relationship, you disable programmatically the ability provided by the superclass **Male**.

I hope it clarifies your question.